# I keep getting a Bad Request error due to a GET in my drf login view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Not sure what the problem is, I originally had a `genericAPIview` used as my user login view that had these errors:

`Method Not Allowed: /auth/login`

and

`"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."`

So I added a `GET` method like so:

```
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    # I ADDED THIS GET METHOD TO SOLVE FOR ABOVE
    def get(self, request, format=None):
         serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
         return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Adding the GET function did solve for `"Method \"GET\" not allowed."`, but now I'm getting this new error:

`Bad Request: /auth/login/`

Here are my app `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', CustomUserCreate.as_view(), name="register"),
    path('login/', LoginAPIView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('home-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', 
]
```

Here are my project `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
   # path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('bucket_api.urls', namespace='bucket_api')),
    path('auth/', include('users.urls')),
    path('home-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

Any tips on how I can solve for the errors above?

EDIT:

`serializer.py`

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=3)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=3, read_only=True)
    
    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tokens(self, obj):
        user = NewUser.objects.get(email=obj['email'])

        return {
            'refresh': user.tokens()['refresh'],
            'access': user.tokens()['access']
        }

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'username', 'tokens']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        password = attrs.get('password', '')
        filtered_user_by_email = NewUser.objects.filter(email=email)
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials, try again')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Account disabled, contact admin')
        if not user.is_verified:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Email is not verified')

        return {
            'email': user.email,
            'username': user.username,
            'tokens': user.tokens()
        }

        return super().validate(attrs)
```

Comment: What for is this GET method, it makes no sense to have it. When do you  do GET request on LoginAPIView?

Comment: That is what I thought and I was doing my research looks like I was heading towards the wrong direction. As @JPG stated, I can simply just return nothing. Thank you for clarifying I was also wondering why I need a GET method in the view! Now I know why, thank you.

Comment: Your problem is now just masked as  you are calling GET somewhere in your code without particular reason for it

Comment: @iklinac, I have added my `serializers.py` code for my login view, care to take another look at my new edit in my original post?

Comment: Your problem is likely on frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to validate or serialize anything at the GET method, just return empty/None

```
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response()

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Oh okay I see now, thank you for the help JPG.

Comment: I have added my serializer code in my original post. Does the GET issue come from there? Or from `genericAPIview` ? Would greatly appreciate a response.

Comment: Actually, you don't need a *get()* method, and conventionally, REST should return a 405response (which is already done by DRF itself). In your case, you are ***trying to*** serialize *"empty data"* (because you are not sending any data to your end-point while you hitting the ***HTTP GET*** method) (are you?) and thus the serializer raises the validation error.

Comment: IMHO, remove the `get()` method and let the DRF raise the HTTP 405 if you have nothing to do with the GET method.